# Control number of PShapes in scene with key input

Tags: processing, shapes

I am trying to make a certain ammount of PShapes display in the scene, this is done by using keys from 0-9. The objects themselves do appear, but respawn endlesly. I am using an arrayList to store them. I suspect there is something wrong with the for loop that reads the shapes from the array... but I cannot figure it out...

```java
    import java.io.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ArrayList;

Random rnd = new Random(); 

PShape torus;
int nTorus;
ArrayList<PShape> toruses;



void settings() {
  size(640, 480, P3D);
}

void setup() {


  toruses = new ArrayList();
}

void draw() {

  background(0);

  for (PShape torus : toruses) {
    pushMatrix();
    translate((int)(rnd.nextDouble() * 1000-1000), (int)(rnd.nextDouble() * 1000-1000), (int)(rnd.nextDouble() * 1000-1000));
    shape(torus);

    popMatrix();
  }
}


void  keyPressed() {



  if (key == '1') {
    nTorus = 1;
  } else if (key == '2') {
    nTorus = 2;
  } else if (key == '3') {
    nTorus = 3;
  } else if (key == '4') {
    nTorus = 4;
  } else if (key == '5') {
    nTorus = 5;
  } else if (key == '6') {
    nTorus = 6;
  } else if (key == '7') {
    nTorus = 7;
  } else if (key == '8') {
    nTorus = 8;
  } else if (key == '9') {
    nTorus = 9;
  } else if (key == '0') {
    nTorus = 0;
  }


  toruses.clear();
  for (int i = 0; i < nTorus; i++) {

    PShape tShape = getTorus((int)(rnd.nextDouble() * 200+50), (int)(rnd.nextDouble() * 100+50), 32, 32);

    toruses.add(tShape);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a few things going on in your code:

- Why are you constantly checking the `key` every time the `draw()` function is called?
- You actually check it twice, since you also call the `createTorus()` function from `draw()` for some reason.
- The `key` variable holds the last pressed key, so that big if statement in your `draw()` function will always be entered.

Instead of constantly checking from the `draw()` function, you'll be better off using the `keyPressed()` function. That way you can take action only when the user actually presses a key. Then from the `draw()` function, the only thing you need to do is actually draw what's in the `ArrayList`.

Here is a small example that takes that approach to draw points based on user input:

```java
ArrayList<PVector> points = new ArrayList<PVector>();

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
}

void keyPressed() {

  int pointCount = 0;

  if (key == '1') {
    pointCount = 1;
  } else if (key == '2') {
    pointCount = 2;
  } else if (key == '3') {
    pointCount = 3;
  } else if (key == '4') {
    pointCount = 4;
  } else if (key == '5') {
    pointCount = 5;
  } else if (key == '6') {
    pointCount = 6;
  } else if (key == '7') {
    pointCount = 7;
  } else if (key == '8') {
    pointCount = 8;
  } else if (key == '9') {
    pointCount = 9;
  }

  points.clear();
  for (int i = 0; i < pointCount; i++) {
    points.add(new PVector(random(width), random(height)));
  }
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  for (PVector point : points) {
    ellipse(point.x, point.y, 10, 10);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I have managed to make them appear in the scene and not respawn like crazy. However if I set a random location to be set it comes back again to the respawning... I am using push/popMatrix and trasnlations to do it.

Comment: @eneko I'd suggest asking a new question. Start with the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I gave you, and only add as much code as is necessary to repeat the problem. It'll be much easier to help you that way.

Comment: Got it working, thanks!! The approach was nice and simple.